# Photo orientation after save VideoBrush to Image

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have problem with make photo on portrait orientation.
I use VideoBrush on for Canvas.Background:

```
 <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,0,12,0">
    <Canvas Name="PhotoCanvas" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="1">
                    <Canvas.Background>
                        <VideoBrush x:Name="viewCamera">
                            <VideoBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                <CompositeTransform x:Name="cameraViewTransform" CenterX=".5" CenterY=".5"/>
                            </VideoBrush.RelativeTransform>
                        </VideoBrush>
                    </Canvas.Background>
     <Image Name="photoImage"></Image>
                   </Canvas>
            </Grid>
```

I save photo and added this photo to photoImage control:

```
Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
{
BitmapImage bImage = new BitmapImage();
bImage.SetSource(e.ImageStream);
photoImage.Source = bImage;
photoImage.Height = PhotoCanvas.ActualHeight;
photoImage.Width = PhotoCanvas.ActualWidth;
Camera.Dispose();
PhotoCanvas.Background = new ImageBrush();
}};
```

But I see photo on landscape orientation after save.

May be my code for orientation videoBrush  brake all?:

```
switch (orientation)
            {
                case PageOrientation.Landscape:
                case PageOrientation.LandscapeLeft:
                    cameraViewTransform.Rotation = 0;
                    break;
                case PageOrientation.LandscapeRight:
                    cameraViewTransform.Rotation = 180;
                    break;
                case PageOrientation.Portrait:
                case PageOrientation.PortraitUp:
                    cameraViewTransform.Rotation = 90;
                    break;
                case PageOrientation.PortraitDown:
                    cameraViewTransform.Rotation = 270;
                    break;
            }
        }
```

How resolve this problem?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the PhotoCaptureDevice? try:

`captureDevice.SetProperty(KnownCameraGeneralProperties.EncodeWithOrientation,
                                  cameraViewTransform.YourOrientation);`

Comment: I don't use PhotoCaptureDevice. How I can use it?

Comment: I use  PhotoCamera and PhotoCamera.CaptureImageAvailable

Comment: I can't make great solution with PhotoCamera and now I'm rewriting code use PhotoCaptureDevice